# Google AppRTC Web Server

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, webrtc

**what i did:**

1. I have download the AppRTC demo for ios from the link https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios
   and also download the WebServer from the link
   https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-server
2. I have tried to install the WebServer into my ubntu 14.04:

   Following Steps I have Followed To Install

   1.Open the terminal

   2.Open the specific directory

   3.Typed the command npm install in the terminal

   4.During installation it's showing an error

**ERROR:**

```
 npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-35-generic

npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"

npm ERR! node v0.10.44

npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0

npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID


npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt@1.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-jinja@0.3.0 wants grunt@~0.4.1

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-shell@1.3.0 wants grunt@>=0.4.0

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-compress@0.13.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jshint@0.10.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-htmlhint@0.9.12 wants grunt@~0.4.1

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-closurecompiler@0.9.9 wants grunt@~0.4.0

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-jstestdriver-phantomjs@0.0.7 wants grunt@~0.4.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!    /home/Downloads/apprtc-server-master/npm-debug.log
```

What I have to do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Modify package.json to:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
     "grunt": ">=0.4.5 <1.0.0",
     ...
 }
```

can resolve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

npm is distributed as part of nodejs.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo npm install -g npm
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 the default packages installs /usr/bin/nodejs but the /usr/bin/node executable is required for grunt. This is installed on some Ubuntu package sets; if it is missing, you can add this by installing the nodejs-legacy package,

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

It is easiest to install a shared version of grunt-cli from npm using the -g flag. This will allow you access the grunt command from /usr/local/bin. More information can be found on gruntjs Getting Started.

```
sudo npm -g install grunt-cli
```

Omitting the -g flag will install grunt-cli to the current directory under the node_modules directory.

Setting up the environment just requires the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-node-server.git ./apprtc-node-server
cd ./apprtc-node-server
 sudo npm install
```

Running the AppRTC Node Server

The apprtc-node-server uses ExpressJS. To run the node server after setup just execute:

```
node ./bin/www
```

Navigate to http://localhost:3000 to run the WebRTC Demo